# Using SXA Partials to insert Renderings hides Placeholder Add button from EE

Tags: sxa, jss

Pretty new to SXA, currently using it on a project with JSS (so not using the built-in renderings or anything like that, but am using Page Designs and Page Partials).

I'm not sure if this is known or expected functionality, so hoping somebody can help me.  I have some page partials, which are all working great. I have Placeholders, with various allowed renderings configured.  If I insert a rendering onto one of these placeholders via a Partial, that placeholder becomes "inactive" in EE - I can no longer add more renderings onto that placeholder. When I hit all placeholder buttons, that placeholder no longer shows up... seems to add a rendering via an SXA partial hides the placeholder Add Rendering button in EE.

Is this expected behavior?  I'm hoping there's a checkbox somewhere that'll set it to "enable renderings from partials and EE" or something like that... but I'm not hopeful. I'm guessing it's a bug, but keen to hear what the community has to say before I raise a Sitecore support request.

I made a video demonstrating what I'm trying to explain above, might be easier to understand by seeing it in action...

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1io_LjYF2t6RfX9NyuNG010gETxiDwg4I/view

Comment: Ah.. I just found this very similar question: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/17568/placeholders-generated-by-partial-design-are-behaving-differently

Comment: Indeed - check that other question and answer. This is expected behavior.